# Why parameters are passed outside the parenthesis () in globals(), locals() and vars() in Python?

Tags: python, function, variables, local-variables, global

I'm very new in Py but I know the syntax function(param1,.. paramN) and I can't understand this:

```
globals()['z'] = 8
```

Could not be more 'standar' ?

```
globals('z') = 8  
# or..
globals(param = 'z') = 8
```

*EDIT*: thanks to all for yours answers, I just have a couple of hours playing with Python

In retrospective it's "obvious" globals() returns a  instance and I acceding to the index when I write globals('z') but the Dict is returned BY REFERENCE because I can change it just doing:

```
globals()['z'] = 8
```

or... just another member suggest:

```
x = globals(); 
x['z'] = 8
```

All the "magic" was just a pointer to the index :)

Comment: `globals()` returns a `dict` that is then indexed by the string `'z'`.

Comment: It's not some funny `globals`-specific syntax. `'z'` just isn't one of the function's arguments.

Comment: @user2357112: so... where is the 'Principle of Least Astonishment' here ? special sintax ? you in another comment tried to ammend but the sintax is there and it's...strange

Comment: @Boctulus: Okay, imagine you have a dict `d = {}` and a function `def get_d(): return d`. Then `get_d()['x'] = 3` is equivalent to `d['x'] = 3`. `globals` works the same way. It's just fetching the global variable dict and setting one of its entries.

Comment: @user2357112 : I catch you but it's a kind of polymorphism not allowed for user-defined-functions. Or can you define a function that accept parameters like globals() ? It's like globals() were implementing a kind of 'Array Interface' not avaiable for anybody else :)

Comment: @Boctulus: The function I've just shown you works exactly like `globals()`. You can do `get_d()['x'] = 3` or `print 4 + get_d()['y']`. The `'x'` or `'y'` *are not parameters to `globals()`*. `globals()` just returns a dict. What you do with that dict is up to you.

Comment: Also, note that no function anywhere in Python will let you do `f(x) = 3`. You can't assign to a function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`globals` is actually a function that takes no parameters and returns a `dict`, which maps the names of identifiers to their values.

Trying typing just `globals()` in a python interpreter and examine the result.

```
>>> z = 8
>>> globals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', 'z': 8, '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
```

Notice the `'z': 8` part.

> But if you run this code you see actually it takes parameters and change that dict / list / whatever: z = 7 globals()['z'] = 8 print("z=", z) # z= 8

Yup, that's true. The `dict` returned by `globals()` *is* where python goes to get the values of global variables, in some sense. Modifying the dict modifies global values directly.

---

As an FYI, you generally shouldn't be doing stuff like `globals()['z'] = 8`. Just do `z = 8` if you're in global scope already (ie, not inside of a function/class), and inside a function, do:

```
def foo():
    global z
    z = 8
```

Comment: But if you run this code you see actually it takes parameters and change that dict / list / whatever. So... what's my question! HOW is possible that SINTAX

Comment: @Boctulus: It doesn't take parameters. It's the same as `x = globals(); x['z'] = 8`.

Comment: @Boctulus Updated my answer to try address your comment. You seem to maybe be confusing this syntax (which comes from the fact that `globals` is returning a `dict`) and the behavior (which comes from the fact that the returned `dict` is where python stores global variables).

Comment: #user2357112 : you are showing globals() in some-how is passing by reference to x.  ???? ok but in the ORGINIAL FORM the sintax still tricky! wired..

Comment: @Boctulus I think you think there's something trickier happening than there actually is. Look up syntax for python `dict`s -- that might make things clearer.